# Using LaTeX expression in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am having difficulty to get $\bar u$ (to denote average of values $u_i$) as label for the x-axis in the output eps figure.
Any help would be appreciated!

Many thanks!

Comment: Not directly an answer to the question, but you might be interested in the pgfplots LaTeX package.  It allows you to embed plot code directly in a LaTeX document.  Thus, it can cope with arbitrarily complex LaTeX math expressions, and if you're going to wind up putting your gnuplot plots into a LaTeX document pgfplots would be one less step.

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried the following, but they might work for you*

You could try the Baltic letter `ū` (*u with macron*) either directly or with Unicode `U+016B` or html `&#363;`

Or you could follow the [advice here](http://www.fnal.gov/docs/products/gnuplot/tutorial/), which seems to imply that something like

```
set xlabel "$\bar{u}$"
```

might work.

Comment: +1 for Baltic letter, how do you know it? Note that `ū` has a smaller bar compared to $\bar{u}$, so the end result will depend on the font, it might not look good.

Comment: @mpiktas: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macron) lists ū for Latvian and Lithuanian.

Comment: I think you need to use a double backslash. Otherwise, it should work with a `latex`, `epslatex`, or `pstricks` terminal.

Answer (score 2):

If your penultimate goal is to embed your plot in a Latex document, you might consider using the [gnuplottex](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/gnuplottex.html) package (as an alternative to [pgfplots](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) which is an awesome package). The idea is rather simple: you write your code chunk in your tex document directly (like you would do with Sweave), et voilà!

Here is an example (grabbed from gnuplot demos):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}

\begin{document}
\begin{gnuplot}[scale=0.95, terminal=epslatex]
set style fill transparent pattern 4 bo
set style function filledcurves y1=0
set clip two    
Gauss(x,mu,sigma) = 1./(sigma*sqrt(2*pi)) * exp( -(x-mu)**2 / (2*sigma**2) )
d1(x) = Gauss(x, 0.5, 0.5)
d2(x) = Gauss(x,  2.,  1.)
d3(x) = Gauss(x, -1.,  2.)
set xrange [-5:5]
set yrange [0:1]
set xlabel "$\\bar x$ values"
unset colorbox    
plot d1(x) fs solid 1.0 lc rgb "forest-green", \
     d2(x) lc rgb "gold", d3(x) lc rgb "red"
\end{gnuplot}
\end{document}
```

You'll need to compile with the `-shell-escape` option to `pdflatex`.

[image]